# Email Alert sending 2 emails

Tags: email

I have a simple email alert that I have setup.

> If Current Item:Version = 1.0 the Email New document alert.
>
> Else Send Modified document Email alert. go to end of workflow.

For some reason When I add a document or modify a document I receive 2 emails.   How get only 1 email alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a one minute pause in front of your email being sent.  There can be a lag  and the email gets triggered twice.

Comment: I noticed something that maybe you can help me with.  If I have checkout enable to edit things seem to work fine, but if not then the version number increases and I don't get my email notification.  Do you know why that is?  Thanks,